# cassandra and windows phone or wpf

Tags: wpf, cassandra, windows-phone

Im thinking of doing a project that uses wpf or windows phone and a Cassandra database hosted on azure with a Ubuntu VM, I have used Cassandra with jsp sites before and wpf with Cassandra on a local database but never through a remote location. Is it possible to query a Cassandra cluster externally hosted from my local wpf application? Im under the impression I need another cloud service to handle the requests and node.js but unsure how that works with a wpf application.

On my local Cassandra cluster I just use the standard datastax csharp driver which works well, but it doesn't query anything apart from my local database, just changing the ip address to my VM's address doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I hadn't set my Cassandra.yaml file properly and created an endpoint for 9042, works perfect now.